# New line separator for each grep result (Even if grep outupt is null)

Tags: bash, grep

If file content is:

```
echo -n "Host is:"; grep -h -E 'host_value'    /file_path
echo -n "IPAD is:"; grep -h -E 'Address_value' /file_path
```

How to force each grep output to be in a separate line even if the grep output is null? 
And how to replace null values with specific string such as 'No value for this parameter'.

For example, if the host_value is hostname but Address_value is null then output should be as below:

```
Host is:hostname  
IPAD is:No value for this parameter
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe assign the result of grep to a variable first.

```sh
HOST=$(grep -h -E 'host_value'    /file_path 2>/dev/null)
ADDR=$(grep -h -E 'Address_value' /file_path 2>/dev/null)

echo "Host is: $HOST"
echo "IPAD is: $ADDR"

# replace null value
DEFAULT="No value for this parameter"
echo "Host is: ${HOST:-$DEFAULT}"
echo "IPAD is: ${ADDR:-$DEFAULT}"
```

See [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for the syntax of `:-`.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` exits with a exit status 1 if there are no matches, so you can simply use `||` to print an empty line or the "no value" message.

Empty line:

```sh
echo -n "Host is:"; grep -h -E 'host_value'    /file_path || echo
echo -n "IPAD is:"; grep -h -E 'Address_value' /file_path || echo
```

Custom message:

```sh
echo -n "Host is:"; grep -h -E 'host_value'    /file_path || echo "No value for this parameter"
echo -n "IPAD is:"; grep -h -E 'Address_value' /file_path || echo "No value for this parameter"
```

Note thought that this will print the empty line/custom message even in other error scenarios, like file not found. To cover those scenarios, you should check that the exit status is really 1.

Comment: Still result in same line

`code` Host is: IPAD is: `code`